# Smartphones as a development platform?

Tags: smartphone

Modern smart phones have more memory, better processors, and bigger hard drives then the computers of the previous era. With that fact in mind I was wondering if there are any compilers/interpreters that run on smart phones?

I'm looking for anything. Even a BASIC interpreter. I'm primarily wondering about BlackBerry's, but if you know of a solution for iPhone's and Android feel free to list those as well.

Comment: @skaffman, he is asking about compilers or interpreters that are smartphone applications, not whether or not it's possible to write software for smartphones. And now I look silly because you deleted your comment.

Comment: I modified this question's title since nobody was reading the actual question.

Comment: Ok I see now - in fairness, the question "With that fact in mind I was wondering if there are any compilers/interpreters for smart phones?" is ambiguous.

Comment: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/repl_lyau.html

Answer (score 1):

Android has a scripting environment called "Scripting Layer for Android": http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/. You can use it to code in python, lua and few other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most smartphones these days have some sort of software development kit available. Certainly the iphone and android do (http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) - very well developed and documented. In fact there are in excess of 30k questions here on stack overflow that deal with just android :-)

Comment: I think downvotes should be reserved for answers that are misleading, badly coded or just wrong. Not for when the question was misread. I almost made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about Blackberry, Android, and iPhone.  They all have SDKs. 
I don't know that much about them but there's a healthy set of questions on stackoverflow covering iphone development.  Not sure about Android. 
I had a blackberry a loooooong time ago, maybe 2000, and there was a java sdk for it then.

I know on Windows phones you can write apps in C# or VB.NET, and run then on the .NET Compact Framework.

So yes, there are compilers that can be used to produce software for smartphones.

Comment: Why don't you relax, or go somewhere where your attitude is more appropriate. I read his question as asking about compilers and interpreters for smart phones. I just read it again and that's *still* what I get. I gave an answer that I still think is appropriate. If you don't agree with my take on it, fine. Don't upvote me. And then go away. The attitude you're copping belongs on Reddit or Digg or something, not here. ps: SEngstrom seems to have a similar take to mine.  Is everyone *except you*, wrong?

Comment: I realize that my question wasn't crystal clear. However your answer is not what I'm looking for. I'm pretty sure you understand this by now. So I see no reason not to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good solution to this, yet, but it wouldn't be too hard to get something simple running.

For example, take [this Javascript repl](http://tech.einaregilsson.com/repl.html) (which has no external dependencies), run it through [Hixie's data: URI kitchen](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data), and you've got an interpreter in a URI.  Visit that URI, tap the arrow-icon in the middle of the bottom toolbar, choose Add to Main Screen, and now you've got an app with a Javascript repl.  There's some extra meta tags you can add to the HTML head to make it more app-like (removing the Safari toolbars, giving it a high-res icon, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for anything, a web based ide might be another option for doing development on a smartphone. I googled for one and there is something called [Jiggy](http://techcrunch.com/2007/12/17/jiggy-an-easy-web-based-ide-for-iphones/) for the iPhone.

Comment: That looked interesting, however the service is no longer available.